# Как создать таблицу с именем, равным id пользователя телегрмм

Tags: python, база-данных, telegram-bot, telegram

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import sqlite3

token = 'тут токен'
client = telebot.TeleBot(token)
people_id,name,cursor,db = '','','',''

def dbconnect():
    global cursor,db
    db = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    cursor = db.cursor()


@client.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    dbconnect()
    people_id = str(message.from_user.id)
    cursor.execute(f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {people_id}(
            name TEXT,
            *** INT,
            *** INT,
            *** INT,
            *** INT,
        )""")
    db.commit()
```

Не создаются таблица в базе данных. Таблица должна иметь имя id пользователя телегрмм.

Сначала код работает, но когда я нажимаю кнопку старт в телеге или ввожу `/start`, выводит ошибку:

> cursor.execute(f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {people_id}(
> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "тут мой айди": syntax error

Comment: перепроверьте то, что передали в cursor.execute()

Answer (score 1):

```
people_id = 'id'+ str(message.from_user.id)
```

Чтоб имя таблицы не начиналось с цифры.