# Как создать таблицу в базе данный sqlite3 с именем id пользователе телеграмма

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram

```
from telebot import types
import sqlite3

token = 'тут токен'
client = telebot.TeleBot(token)
people_id,name,cursor,db = '','','',''

def dbconnect():
    global cursor,db
    db = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    cursor = db.cursor()


@client.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    dbconnect()
    people_id = str(message.from_user.id)
    cursor.execute(f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {people_id}(
            name TEXT,
            *** INT,
            *** INT,
            *** INT,
            *** INT,
        )""")
    db.commit()
```

Не создаётся таблица в базе данных. Таблица должна иметь имя id пользователя телеграмм
Сначала код работает, но когда я нажимаю кнопку старт в телеге или ввожу /start, выводит ошибку

```
cursor.execute(f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {people_id}(
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "тут мой айди": syntax error.
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как создать таблицу с именем, равным id пользователя телегрмм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1461629/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-id-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%bc)

Comment: Это мой вопрос но ответа я нормального не получил

Comment: В переменной people_id содержатся только цифры и/или буквы? Возможно присутствуют лишние символы, которые нарушают запрос. Допустим двойные кавычки

Comment: Ещё, у вас не хватает точки в dbconnect(). Плюс, ещё нужно закрывать подключение, если не ошибаюсь (привык к контекстному менеджеру with, там ни открывать, ни закрывать не надо)

Comment: Идея гавно. Не нужно создавать таблицы под каждого. Создавай строки с ключом.